# Error importing XML file on Remote service provider : Forgerock AM 7.1.0

Tags: saml-2.0, forgerock

I get the following error on the admin panel when I try to import the Service provider metadata file on the Remote service provider section of the AM 7.1.0.

```
Exception from invocation expected to be handled by promise
```

[image]

No other error can be seen on the console. I'm trying to set up a SAML 2.0 IDP.

Error from debug log:

> [CONTINUED]Caused by: org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NOT_FOUND_ERR: An attempt is made to reference a node in a context where it does not exist.
> [CONTINUED] at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementImpl.setIdAttribute(ElementImpl.java:965)
> [CONTINUED] at com.sun.identity.saml2.meta.SAML2MetaSecurityUtils.verifySignature(SAML2MetaSecurityUtils.java:269)
> [CONTINUED] at com.sun.identity.saml2.meta.SAML2MetaUtils.preProcessSAML2Document(SAML2MetaUtils.java:602)
> [CONTINUED] at com.sun.identity.saml2.meta.SAML2MetaUtils.importSAML2Document(SAML2MetaUtils.java:579)
> [CONTINUED] at org.forgerock.openam.federation.rest.remote.RemoteEntitiesCollectionProvider.importEntity(RemoteEntitiesCollectionProvider.java:127)
> [CONTINUED] ... 156 common frames omitted
> [CONTINUED]java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception from invocation expected to be handled by promise
> at org.forgerock.json.resource.AnnotatedMethod.invoke(AnnotatedMethod.java:100)
> at org.forgerock.json.resource.AnnotatedMethod.invoke(AnnotatedMethod.java:65)

Comment: Which error do you get in AM debug logs? Would you be able to share the SP's meta data?

Comment: Where can I find the debug logs? No error showing in the tomcat console. Sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: It seems the SAML SP meta data is not correctly digitally singed.

Comment: This data was generated by the Liferay DXP platform automatically after configuring the IDP info. After searching online for a while, I found the cause which is same as you mentioned. ds:signature metdadata needs to be removed from the XML before impoeting it into the IDP. Thanks for info.